# Bitbucket (Git version) push doesn't understand (messes the) IE8 CSS hack

Tags: internet-explorer-8, bitbucket

I'm having some weird problem with an IE8 CSS hack. It works perfectly on local, I've committed and it's fine. The problem arises after I push the project to Bitbucket. The "\" of the CSS hack gets highlighted in red in the "push" comments, I'm assuming it doesn't understand it or something of the sort.

```
width: 0px\0/; /*IE8*/
```

When I push the project it *finishes successfully*, no error gets spouted. It's after the push that the error is spouted in BitBucket. I have tried different "escape" character combinations such as:

```
\\\0/
/\0/
```

But to no avail. Help is much appreciated.

Comment: Which version control system is this for, Git or Mercurial?

Comment: I've added it in the title: Git